# Getting treeId for SAPGuiLibrary

Tags: robotframework, sap-gui

i need to automate the selection of the Tree node using [sapguilibrary](https://github.com/frankvanderkuur/robotframework-sapguilibrary/)

as per the document i am using [Select Node](https://frankvanderkuur.github.io/SapGuiLibrary.html#Select%20Node) keyword but i am not getting what is tree_id means(I am not SAP developer).

i used the [tracker](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/20/scripting-tracker-development-tool-for-sap-gui-scripting/) to get the element_id but document says we can use the tracker or recorder for the same

Can you please help me on this

Below is the image of  SAPLogon and Tracker which is "spro" tcode[image]

Here i can see shell but not the tree_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found out

tree_id is nothing but the shell

i have taken example of "SAP Easy Access"

[image]

tree_id is

```
/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell
```

and the node_id is taken from the recorder

[image]

```
Select Node    /app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell   0000000003
```

Will click on "Office" node